# What are the ideas to handle outliers effectively in dataset without removing it

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, outliers

I'm a beginner in data science. Facing a challenge while attending hackathon. Im having a train dataset with lots of outliers in many columns. Same with test data (Train and test data provided separately). I cannot remove outliers straight away in train set since test set also having similar characteristics. If i do removal in my test then my test data row count decreases which will throw error while submission.
Please can any one guide me in handling outlier effectively. Scaling and log conversion also did not help much.

Comment: The question is very broad. Try to be more concrete.

Answer (score 1):

Well. How to detect & handle outlier is one of my interested topic.

I would like answer it. It can be answer from two viewpoint.

1. In the machine learning competition, you has to preprocess data(train and test) before training & predict. Usually, you should build a pipeline which include 
   Stage1 .preprocess( clean, transform, add/remove features, normalize/standardize)
   Stage2 .Trainging 
   Stage3 .Cross Validation
   Stage4. Stacking
   Stage5. Predicting.
   The above process has to be repeated in most of competiton case to reach a good score. And there is a lot of tricks you can find in Kaggle.
2. The outlier.
   Without proper detect & handle outlier, you model score will be suck especially for regression type of competition. The outlier influence the data significantly.
   Here is my way to deal the outliers. 
   **for univariable, (you can check the outlierlier in features in one by one mode),** 
    **detect**: if the data - data.mean()/data.std()>3, you should has confidence it is outlier.
    handle: replace it with mode(), or mean() or median() based on insight understanding of data. if you know the univariable has linear relation with another variable, you can apply aggregated mean, mode, median.

   **for multi variable ( all feature work together to find certain features outlier).**
   I am exploring the way as well. the key challenge is train/test data has to be splitted. otherwise dataleaking will happpend.
   the possible mode is :
   if you has X1,X2,X3, Y in train, X1,X2,X3 in test. 
   to detect X(i) outlier, you can use X(i) as new_y, the rest X(j)s has new_x.
   and use statemodels.api functions like below:

   import statsmodels.api as sm

   X_od =data[X1] #assuming we want to find Data[X1] outliers
   Y_od= data[[X2,X3]]
   lm=sm.OLS(X_od,Y_od).fit() #it is OLS line regression

   print(lm)
   outliers_test = lm.outlier_test() # it use residual error to detect outliers
   print(outlier_test.query('"unadj_p"<0.05)) #if the unad p value less than 5%, we know there are outliers.

[image: Check The R-Square]
Usually R-Square might higher than 50%, it too low, there is outlier or something wrong. in some extremy case the R2 is less than 0.5%.

[image: Bonferroni outlier test result]

**handle:** 
   way1. add new columns called OD_flag_X1 and set the detected outlier as 1. other keep 0.
   way2. replace the detected outlier with other aggregated value(mean,mode, median or others) 
   combined way1 and way2.
   as I said earlier. You has add the outlier detect/handle in the pipeline to avoid data leaking or step missing.

This is my way to detect & handle outlier.

Hope it can help you or other readers.